# sched_setaffinity and glibc - cross-compilation

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, glibc

I'm using a full system simulator (GEM5) with the Alpha ISA. I have successfully cross-compiled (with gcc-4.3.2, glibc-2.6.1) Linux 2.6.27 for Alpha. Now, I am cross compiling my own program which calls the sched_setaffinity function. The program compiles, but during runtime it returns -1 with the errno being "Function not implemented". The function is indeed implemented in my cross-compiled kernel (in kernel/sched.c) but that implementation never gets called.

I believe the issue may be with sched_setaffinity not being defined/implemented in the glibc (libc-2.3.5.so) on the Alpha disk image. If I simply replace libc-2.3.5.so with an updated cross-compiled version, it makes other programs on the disk image not work. I believe sched_setaffinity should already be present in libc-2.3.5.so by default. Is there a way I can force my program to use the implementation in the kernel? What could be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To call the `perf_event_open` system call that doesn't have libc wrapper I am using the following function:

```
static long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags)
{
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu,
                   group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}
```

May be you should be able to do a similar function to directly call the system call used by the libc sched_set_affinity function. Looking in my Linux source tree version 3.11.0 I can see the following line in the `include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h`

```
#define __NR_sched_setaffinity 122
```

Comment: __NR_sched_setaffinity is defined in several asm-* directories (asm-x86, cris, xtensa, m32r, mips, parisc, mn10300, m68k, frv) but not in generic. I tried calling syscall with all the different definitions, but errno keeps being "Invalid argument". Also I don't have a "unistd.h" in my asm-generic directory. Should I define my own somewhere? What would be the proper way?